# How to use Chrome extension get Laravel passport token?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm working on using Chrome extension access Laravel passport API. Currently, the Laravel passport API is setup and working. I tried to use `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` to get passport token but not working. There is an example provided by [Google](http://OAuth2:%20Authenticate%20Users%20with%20Google), it is different from my use case.

I have two questions:

1. According to the Laravel [document](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport), the first step is `request an authorization code`, the API end point is `/oauth/authorize`. What the `redirect_uri` should be since it is a chrome extension but not a website?
2. After the user approve the request, I'm using `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` to get the access token from Passport. In laravel it is a POST request, the end point is `/oauth/token`. But I tried  `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`, it is a GET request.

I can make this whole process working  using PHP but not Chrome Extension. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) docs:

> When the provider redirects to a URL matching the pattern https://app-id.chromiumapp.org/*, the window will close, and the final redirect URL will be passed to the callback function.

As an example, you could use the following code:

```
let redirectUrl = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('redirect');

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    url: `https://my.app.domain.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_type=code&scope=&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}`
}, (redirectUrl) => {
    console.log(redirectUrl) // Redirect URL with oauth query params added
})
```

Comment: I tried and generated the redirectUrl. But the redirect URL in the callback function is still undefined.

Comment: I changed the redirect url in laravel table `oauth_clients`, now I can get the authorization_code. It is not the access token. How to get the token?

Comment: See the `Converting Authorization Codes To Access Tokens` section of the laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#requesting-tokens

Comment: Yes, It's working now. I'm using another POST request to get `Access Token`. Thanks for asking.